# Extend Javascript promise and resolve or reject it inside constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, es6-promise, es6-class

I want to extend native Javascript Promise class with ES6 syntax, and be able to call some asynchronous function inside the subclass constructor. Based on async function result the promise must be either rejected or resolved.

However, two strange things happen when `then` function is called:

1. subclass constructor is executed twice
2. "Uncaught TypeError: Promise resolve or reject function is not callable" error is thrown

```js
    class MyPromise extends Promise {
        constructor(name) {
            super((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve(1)
                }, 1000)
            })

            this.name = name
        }
    }

    new MyPromise('p1')
        .then(result => {
            console.log('resolved, result: ', result)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('err: ', err)
        })
```

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13678#issuecomment-326812117

Comment: Relevant discussion at [Extending a Promise in javascript](/q/41792036).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reasoning is simple but not necessarily self evident.

- `.then()` returns a promise
- if `then` is called on a subclass of Promise, the returned promise is an instance of the subclass, not Promise itself.
- the `then` returned promise is constructed by calling the subclass constructor, and passing it an internal executor function that records the value of `resolve` and `reject` arguments passed to it for later use.
- "later use" covers resolving or rejecting the promise returned by `then` asynchronously when monitoring execution of `onfulfilled` or `onrejected` handlers (later) to see if they return a value (which resolves the `then` returned promise) or throw an error (which rejects the promise).

*In short `then` calls internally obtain and record references to the `resolve` and `reject` functions of promises they return.*

---

So regarding the question,

```
new MyPromise( 'p1')
```

works fine and is the first call to the subclass constructor.

```
.then( someFunction)
```

records `someFunction` in a list of `then` calls made on `new MyPromise` (recall `then` can be called multiple times) and attempts to create a return promise by calling

```
new MyPromise( (resolve, reject) => ... /* store resolve reject references */
```

This is the second call to the subclass constructor coming from `then` code. The constructor is expected to (and does) return synchronously.

On return from creating the promise to return, the `.then` method makes an integrity check to see if the `resolve` and `reject` functions it needs for later use are in fact functions. They should have been stored (in a list) along with callbacks provided in the `then` call.

In the case of `MyPromise` they are not. The executor passed by `then`, to `MyPromise`, is not even called. So `then` method code throws a type error "Promise resolve or reject function is not callable" - it has no means of resolving or rejecting the promise it is supposed to return.

When creating a subclass of Promise, the subclass constructor must take an executor function as its first argument, and call the executor with real `resolve` and `reject` functional arguments. This is internally required by `then` method code.

Doing something intricate with `MyPromise`, perhaps checking the first parameter to see if it is a function and calling it as an executor if it is, may be feasible but is outside the scope of this answer! For the code shown, writing a factory/library function may be simpler:

```js
function namedDelay(name, delay=1000, value=1) {
     var promise = new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
         setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(value)
            }, delay)
         }
     );
    promise.name = name;
    return promise;
}

namedDelay( 'p1')
    .then(result => {
        console.log('fulfilled, result: ', result)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('err: ', err)
    })
```

---

**;TLDR**

The class extension to Promise is not an extension. If it were it would need to implement the Promise interface and take an executor function as first parameter. You could use a factory function to return a Promise which is resolved asynchronously (as above), or **hack** the posted code with

```
MyPromise.prototype.constructor = Promise
```

which causes `.then` to return a regular Promise object. The hack itself refutes the idea that a class extension is taking place.

---

**Promise Extension Example**

The following example shows a basic Promise extension that adds properties supplied to the constructor. Of note:

- The [`Symbol.toString` getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag#custom_tag_with_tostringtag) only affects the output of converting an instance to a string. It does not change "Promise" to "MyPromise" when logging an instance *object* on browser consoles tested.
- Firefox 89 (Proton) is not reporting own properties of extended instances while Chrome does - the reason test code below logs instance properties by name.

```js
class MyPromise extends Promise {
    constructor(exec, props) {
        if( typeof exec != "function") {
            throw TypeError( "new MyPromise(executor, props): an executor function is required");
        }
        super((resolve, reject) => exec(resolve,reject));
        if( props) {
            Object.assign( this, props);
        } 
    }
    get [Symbol.toStringTag]() {
        return 'MyPromise';
    }
}

// Test the extension:
const p1 = new MyPromise( (resolve, reject) =>
    resolve(42),
    {id: "p1", bark: ()=>console.log("woof") });

console.log( "p1 is a %s object", p1.constructor.name);
console.log( "p1.toString() = %s", p1.toString());
console.log( "p1.id = '%s'", p1.id);
console.log( "p1 says:"); p1.bark();

const pThen = p1.then(data=>data);
console.log( "p1.then() returns a %s object", pThen.constructor.name);
let pAll = MyPromise.all([Promise.resolve(39)]);
console.log( "MyPromise.all returns a %s object", pAll.constructor.name);
try { new MyPromise(); }
catch(err) {
    console.log( "new MyPromise() threw: '%s'", err.message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @traktor53 for complete logic description.
Something like https://jsfiddle.net/p7b6gaqd/15/ should work as well I guess?

Comment: @Soul_man the code appears to be going in the right direction but as mentioned is "outside the scope of this answer". Given comments are not the place to extend existing questions, please ask a new question, either here or on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you wish additional assistance and/or feedback. It also gives others the chance to answer :-)

Comment: So, because the `MyPromise`’s constructor, not `Promise`’s, is used to construct _derived_ `Promise`s, just as `Promise`’s would do, you’ve got to run the given executor (if any) and feed it proper `resolve` and `reject` functions you got from the super class, `Promise`, in the `MyPromise`’s constructor. Okay, I think I got it.

Comment: I'm trying to add a readable state to the Promise object by extending the Promise class using ES6. However, due to what you explained, calling `.then` inside the constructor (even if called on the `super` object) causes a recursion error. Any idea on how I could achieve that?

Comment: @Plagiatus I would start with not returning the `this` promise in the constructor - add suitable handlers to `this` to add state and value properties to another promise returned instead of `this`. Faking the returned promise to be an instance of the extended class would be tricky but probably doable. _Trying to do this is a very bad way of trying to program your way out of an X-Y problem_, and would essentially invite inexperienced programmers to use polling instead of promise state listeners - if  you succeed, don't mention it in an interview.

Comment: I believe in standing up for your mistakes and wacky solutions, as they helped you learn in the end. ;) But I appreciate the guidance nontheless, I have since found a different solution to the problem that I was trying to solve through this X-Y solution.

Comment: Should have added a wink at the end of my last comment. Take care.

Answer (score 12):

The best way I found to extend a promise is

```
class MyPromise extends Promise {
    constructor(name) {
        // needed for MyPromise.race/all ecc
        if(name instanceof Function){
            return super(name)
        }
        super((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(1)
            }, 1000)
        })

        this.name = name
    }

    // you can also use Symbol.species in order to
    // return a Promise for then/catch/finally
    static get [Symbol.species]() {
        return Promise;
    }

    // Promise overrides his Symbol.toStringTag
    get [Symbol.toStringTag]() {
        return 'MyPromise';
    }
}


new MyPromise('p1')
    .then(result => {
        console.log('resolved, result: ', result)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('err: ', err)
    })
```

Comment: I used a similar approach for my [`CancellablePromise`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/207116) but I wasn't aware of the `[theSymbol.species]` trick, thanks for that!

Comment: Also: [Constructor of a custom promise class is called twice (extending standard Promise)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53146565/1768303).

Comment: From: [MDN's Symbol.species](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species): ***Warning: The existence of `@@species` allows execution of arbitrary code and may create security vulnerabilities. It also makes certain optimizations much harder. Engine implementers are [investigating whether to remove this feature](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-rm-builtin-subclassing). Avoid relying on it if possible.***

Answer (score 8):

The post by `asdru` contains the correct answer, but also contains an approach (constructor hack) that should be discouraged.

The constructor hack checks if the constructor argument is a function. This is ***not*** the way to go as the ECMAScript design contains a specific mechanism for sub-classing Promises via `Symbol.species`.

`asdru`'s comment on using `Symbol.species` is correct. See the explanation in the current [ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-get-promise-@@species):

> Promise prototype methods normally use their this value's constructor
> to create a derived object. However, a subclass constructor may
> over-ride that default behaviour by redefining its @@species property.

The specification (indirectly) refers to this note in the sections on `finally` and `then` (look for mentions of `SpeciesConstructor`).

By returning `Promise` as the species constructor, the problems that `traktor`'s answer analyzes so clearly are avoided. `then` calls the `Promise` constructor, but not the sub-classed `MyPromise` constructor. The `MyPromise` constructor is called only once with the `name` argument and no further argument-checking logic is needed or appropriate.

Therefore, the code should simply be:

```
class MyPromise extends Promise {
    constructor(name) {
        super((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(1)
            }, 1000)
        })
        this.name = name
    }

    static get [Symbol.species]() {
        return Promise;
    }

    get [Symbol.toStringTag]() {
        return 'MyPromise';
    }
}
```

Less is more!

Some notes:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species) has an example for the use of the species symbol in extending `Array`.
- The most recent browser versions (Chrome, FF, Safari, Edge on MAC and Linux) handle this correctly, but I have no information on other browsers or legacy versions.
- `Symbol.toStringTag` is a very nice touch, but not required. Most browsers use the value returned for this symbol to identify the sub-classed promise in the console, but, beware, FF does not - this could easily be confusing. In all browsers, however, `new MyPromise('mine').toString()` yields `"[object MyPromise]"`.
- All of this is also unproblematic if you author in Typescript.
- As `noseratio` points out, a primary use-case for extending Promises is the wrapping of (legacy) APIs that support abort or cancel logic (FileReader, fetch, ...).

Comment: But if you don't maintain the compatibility with the `Promise` constructor you will not be able to use `MyPromise.race` and `MyPromise.all`, breaking the LSP SOLID principle. for the `Symbol.toStringTag`, yes is pretty useless, I added it just for sake of completeness

Comment: Returning `Promise` from the `Symbol.species`  getter causes calls to the `then` method of  MyPromise objects to return a Promise object instead a `MyPromise` object, making the extension partial at best. If you omit the Symbol.species getter, calls to the inherited `then` method of Mypromise objects throw  an error because the "extended" class constructor doesn't support an executor function (as described in the post).

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it *`then`able* by implementing the `then` method.

Otherwise, that of the superclass, `Promise`, will be called, and it’ll try to create another `Promise` with your `MyPromise`’ constructor, which is not compatible with the original `Promise` constructor.

The thing is, it’s tricky to properly implement the `then` method that works just like `Promise`’s does. You’ll likely end up having an instance of `Promise` as a member, not as a superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the above into a short tl;dr for those who just want to get something working and move on, you just need to add this to your class body:

```js
    static get [Symbol.species]() {
        return Promise;
    }
```

A full TypeScript example:

```
class MyPromise extends Promise<string> {
    constructor(name: string) {
        super((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(name)
            }, 1000)
        })
        this.name = name;
    }

    static get [Symbol.species]() {
        return Promise;
    }
}

const p = new MyPromise('hi');
p.name === 'hi'
const x: string = await p;
x === 'hi'
```

That's all you need.

Forgoing `Symbol.toStringTag` may make `MyPromise` just look like a `Promise` in some debugging contexts, and you won't be able to do `MyPromise.race` or `MyPromise.all`, but that's fine: you can use `Promise.all` with a list of `MyPromise`s.