# Why can't I use "this" in an arrow function in a call to the super constructor?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm trying to create a deferred promise constructor, like so:

```
class DeferredPromise extends Promise {
  constructor() {
    super((resolve, reject) => {
      this.resolve = resolve
      this.reject = reject
    })
  }
}
```

However, when I try to use `new DeferredPromise()`, I get the following error in Firefox 60.0.01

```
ReferenceError: must call super constructor before using |this| in arrow function in derived class constructor
```

Why do I get this error and how can I get around it? Also, if there's a better solution to this please let me know.

Comment: The call to `super` has to happen before you reference `this`. Also not clear why you don't just use `Promise.resolve(something)` or `Promise.reject(someError)`.

Comment: FYI, if you're just looking for a simple Deferred object implementation, there are several already here on stack overflow.  Here's one: [Deferred implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651780/why-does-the-promise-constructor-need-an-executor/37673534#37673534).

Answer (score 2):

`this` isn't allowed in child classes before parent constructor call (`super`) because `this` doesn't certainly exist before that (parent class can return another object instead of `this`). This ES6 class restriction is enforced by the specification.

As [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Sub_classing_with_extends) states,

> If there is a constructor present in subclass, it needs to first call super() before using "this".

If it's known that `this` is used inside the function only after parent constructor call, it can be safely used:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(callback) {
    this.doFoo = callback;
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  constructor() {
    super(() => {
      this.doBar();
    })
  }

  doBar() {}
}

new Bar().doFoo();
```

Otherwise `this` should be referred only after parent constructor call:

```
class DeferredPromise extends Promise {
  constructor() {
    let resolve, reject;

    super((_resolve, _reject) => {
      resolve = _resolve;
      reject = _reject;
    });

    this.resolve = resolve;
    this.reject = reject;
  }
}
```

This will cause a problem specific to `Promise` and described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48159603/3731501), the suggested solution is:

```
DeferredPromise.prototype.constructor = Promise;
```

This means that `DeferredPromise` instance needs to be stored to access `resolve` and `reject` methods, they won't be available in chained promises:

```
let deferred = new DeferredPromise();
let nonDeferred = deferred.catch(() => {});
// nonDeferred.reject === undefined
```

This is the case for [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Deferred pattern doesn't need promise class to be extended, doing that has no obvious benefits. An implementation can be as simple as:

```
class Deferred {
  constructor() {
    this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.resolve = resolve;
      this.reject = reject;
    });
  }
}
```